# How to get current slide position or number in react-native flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-animatable

Hy, I'm creating a slider in react-native. It works perfectly. It having three slides on scrolling. I done this using Animated.FlatList and scrollX. But One thing I'm not getting is how I can know which slide is currently displaying. I want to because it onboard screen I want to display the skip button on the first two slides and on the third I want to display something else button how I can do that.

```
const OnBoardScreen = () => {
  const scrollX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;  
  // flatlist render function
  const renderSplash = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainWrapper}>
        <View style={styles.imageWrapper}>{item.image}</View>
        <View style={[styles.titleWrapper,
            {marginTop:index==1 ? hp(4):index == 2 ? hp(10):null}
        ]}>
          <Text style={styles.titleText}>{item.title}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.bodyWrapper}>
          <Text style={styles.bodyText}>{item.body}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* background Svgs */}
      <View style={styles.blueSvgWrapper}>
        <BlueSvg />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.dotSvgWrapper}>
        <DotsSvg />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.orangeSvgWrapper}>
        <OrangeSvg />
      </View>
      {/* Main Content */}

      <Animated.FlatList
        data={onBoardData}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
        renderItem={renderSplash}
        horizontal
        scrollEventThrottle={32}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }],
          { useNativeDriver: false }
        )}
        pagingEnabled
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      />

      <Indicator scrollX={scrollX} />
     {skip == false ?
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.skipWrapper} >
        <Text style={styles.skipText}  >Skip</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
     : null }
    
    </View>
  );
};
```

I try to do conditions on ***scrollX*** but it's not updating the value like states do.

My Issue:
How to know apply condition on slides which thing should be show or which not?

Comment: You could, maybe, calculate it based on the scroll position and the slide width. If the slide takes 100% width then just check the `scrollX` value.

Comment: how @merko thats possible?

Answer (score 1):

FlatList inherits all of ScrollView props.
Therefore you can use onScroll.

```
onScroll = (event) => {
  const scrollOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y
}
```